# Regex - Matching multiple URLs that don't contain specific queries

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to match the following URLs.
I want to avoid matching anything that contains the query `?view=alt`.

There are 2 different paths to the same page that need to be included.

For example:

`ourwebsite.com/products/(product-name)`
`ourwebsite.com/collections/(collection-name)/products/(product-name)`

I need to include both URL options.

Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/products/product-name`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/products/product-name?view=alt`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/collections/collection-name/products/product-name?view=alt`

Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/collections/collection-name/products/product-name`

Match: `https://ourwebsite.co.uk/products/product-name?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=mof&rs=facebook2_6125507649009_6125720949209_6134410260209&fbclid=IwAR31D2CHnvar5p1Ce0ZoYaHTJRPwaN9aa2q3dsyDu3hGCLkjKNtti3pDm2`

Don't Match: `https://mywebsite/products/product-name?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=mof&rs=facebook2_6125507649009_6125720949209_6134410260209&fbclid=IwAR31D2CHnvar5p1Ce0ZoYaHTJRPwaN9aa2q3dsyDu3hGCLkjKNtti3pDm2I&view=alt`

Don't Match: `https://mywebsite/products/product-name?view=alt&utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=mof&rs=facebook2_6125507649009_6125720949209_6134410260209&fbclid=IwAR31D2CHnvar5p1Ce0ZoYaHTJRPwaN9aa2q3dsyDu3hGCLkjKNtti3pDm`2I

Don't Match: `https://google.com/products/product-name`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/products/`

I have already tried multiple different expressions but this is the closest I've got. However when I make the (product-name) part of the expression variable it doesn't work.

`(.*)(ourwebsite\.co\.uk)\/(products|collections)\/((?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*)?)(:?\/products\/)?(product-name)(?!\?view=alt).*`

Variable product name:

`(.*)(ourwebsite\.co\.uk)\/(products|collections)\/((?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*)?)(:?\/products\/)([A-Za-z0-9-][^?\s]*)(?!\?view=alt).*`

I can't seem to get it to work with a variable product name, though.

Link:

https://regex101.com/r/nGtWaC/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using to run that regex?

Comment: It's for URL targeting in Google Optimize. I'm not sure which type of regex they implement. https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6283424?hl=en Currently I'm trying to test it in https://regex101.com/r/nGtWaC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the following :

```
https://www\.ourwebsite\.co\.uk/(?:collections/[^/]*/)?products/[^/?]+(?!.*\bview=alt\b).*
```

Or with slashes escaped if necessary :

```
https:\/\/www\.ourwebsite\.co\.uk\/(?:collections\/[^\/]*\/)?products\/[^\/?]+(?!.*\bview=alt\b).*
```

This matches a whole line that starts with your website's domain name, optionnaly follows with the collections substring, then follows with the product substring, then makes sure there is no `view=alt` substring (whole words) up to the end of the line, which it then matches.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pacF9r/3) !

Comment: Collection-name and product-name are variable. It could be any collection or product name.

Comment: I think I can solve it based on this! :) `(.*ourwebsite\.co\.uk\/)(?:collections|products)?\/(.*)\/(?:products)?\/[^?\s]*(?!.*\bview=alt\b).*`

Comment: `(?!.*\bview=alt\b)` I think this is the part I had all wrong.

Comment: @JoelDorne I've edited to handle variable product-name/category-name (I thought you were searching for specific ones and they were placeholders). Yeah the `(?!.*\bview=alt\b)` is what does it : it looks up to the end of the string, making sure there's no `view=alt` anywhere. Look up lookarounds (more specifically negative lookahead) for more info

Comment: Ah I see you tried using it already. The problem is that you didn't look up to the end of the string (the `.*` at the start of the lookahead). By default it just means "check without matching that what follows is/ is not that", you need a `.*` or similar to make it look further, i.e. "check that what follows is / isn't whatever followed by that"

Comment: I've got it working with this `.*ourwebsite\.co\.uk\/(?:collections\/(.*)\/)?(products)\/([^\?\s]*)(?!.*view=.*).*` But `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/products/` is matching. How can I avoid that? https://regex101.com/r/pacF9r/2

Comment: Do you need the capturing groups? Otherwise `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/(?:collections/[^/]*/)?products/[^/?]*(?!.*\bview=alt\b).*` seems to work well (in regex101 you'll get matches spanning multiple lines but I expect that shouldn't be a problem in your target environment)

Comment: If you need to exclude any `view=` parameter use `(?!.*\bview=)` instead of `(?!.*\bview=alt\b)`

Comment: I was missing the mandatory product-name part in my previous comment, see the updated answer. I've also edited my regex101 link in which I exclude `\n` in the product part to make it work in regex101 but I expect that shouldn't be necessary in your target environment

Comment: I don't need the capturing groups, I was just using them to make sure it was selecting the correct thing as regex101 highlights the groups. Thank you so much! It working perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear it !

Comment: I have one more thing. `(?!.*\bview=.*\b).*` Is that correct if I want anything that view= to not be accepted? Also are there any books you would recommend on regex? I seem to have not properly understood forward Lookahead and Lookbehind as I have never seen examples of it used like `?!.*` that. I understand what it does but nothing I've read taught it.

Comment: `(?!.*\bview=)` would probably be preferable as it avoids matching more than necessary (keep the `.*` after the lookahead if you need the regex to match the whole text, instead of just validating it). If you may have `...&view=&...` parameters which you wouldn't want to exclude then I'd use `(?!\bview=[^&])`. I can't recommend any book but regular-expressions.info has in-depth explanations about regexs, [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)'s their page on lookarounds

Comment: I forgot the `.*` in the second lookahead of the previous comment. `(?!.*\bview=\b)` would also work since there would be no word-boundary between the equal sign and the `&` if they are next to each-other, while there would be one if there is a (alphanumeric) value for the view attribute